# Limits $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\int_x^{2x}\frac{e^t}{t}dt$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{x}\int_x^{2x}\frac{e^t}{t}dt$.

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals

Let us consider the following two limits:
$$1) \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\int_x^{2x}\frac{e^t}{t}dt$$
$$2) \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{x}\int_x^{2x}\frac{e^t}{t}dt$$
For the first, since
$$e^{x} \int_x^{2x}\frac{1}{t}dt\leq\int_x^{2x}\frac{e^t}{t}dt\leq e^{2x} \int_x^{2x}\frac{1}{t}dt$$
and $\int_x^{2x}\frac{1}{t}dt=\ln 2$, for $x\rightarrow 0$ we have (by comparison theorem) that
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\int_x^{2x}\frac{e^t}{t}dt=\ln 2$$
For the second, by denoting $F(x)=\int_0^{x}\frac{e^t}{t}dt$ and by applying L'Hôpital's rule:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{x}\int_x^{2x}\frac{e^t}{t}dt=\left[\int_x^{2x}\frac{e^t}{t}dt\right]'=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \left[F(2x)-F(x)\right]'=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \left(2F'(2x)-F'(x)\right)$$
The result is $1$.

Now we come to my question. If first limit is $=\ln 2$, I would expect that the second $\rightarrow \infty$. Why this did not happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your second calculation is wrong: firstly, since you discovered that the limit of the numerator exists and is nonzero, you don't have an indeterminate form and cannot apply L'Hôpital's Rule.

To compute the limit, you can use the same technique you used in the first bit, to see it blows up. Or note that the integral is the average value of the function on $[x,2x]$, and hence must be between the maximum and minimum of the function:
$$ \frac{e^{2x}}{2x} \leqslant \frac{1}{x}\int_x^{2x} \frac{e^t}{t} \, dt \leqslant \frac{e^x}{x}, $$
for sufficiently small $x$, when the function is decreasing in $x$. Hence it is bounded below by $e^x/x \to \infty$, and hence does diverge as you suppose.